# Could anybody provide a regular expression for select from the last comma ( field Z) only the numbers with decimal begining with 0

Tags: regex, decimal

Could anybody provide a regular expression for select from the last comma ( field Z) only the numbers with decimal begining with 0 ?

```
x,y,z
-37833.6,-47102.7,39.0700
-37817.9600,-47102.9900,40.1900
-37808.7900,-47107.7000,40.3700
-37799.9600,-47106.9900,40.0400
-37815.4200,-47099.2900,40.3100
-37839.3100,-47111.4200,39.1400
-37847.9300,-47127.3800,38.0100
-37854.6200,-47139.7300,38.3600
-37861.2000,-47152.8700,38.0100
```

i´ve tried in notepad++  `^\d+(\.0\d+)?$`   but this is only for one field. My example has 3 fields. I only want to select the Z field

Answer (score 2):

In the pattern you use, this part `\.0\d+` matches at least 2 digits.

If you also want to match for example `38.0`, here are a few other options.

---

A positive lookbehind `(?<=,)` (if supported), asserting a comma to the left

```
(?<=,)\d+\.0\d*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/boedwz/1)

Using `\K` forgetting what is matched so far when using pcre:

```
,\K\d+\.0\d*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OVhYdo/1)

Using a capture group, matching the comma first:

```
,(\d+\.0\d*)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/k6b0Sw/1)

---

The core of the patterns are matching:

- `\d+` match 1 or more digits
- `\.0` Match a dot and a zero
- `\d*` Match optional digits 0-9
- `$` Assert the end of the string

Answer (score 1):

This selects all last column numbers whose first digit after the decimal point is `0`:

```
\d+\.0\d*$
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/qWRVyMprRrZxeP).

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question.

You can try this:

`(?<=,)(0\.\d+)`

`(?<=,)`: This is a lookbehind that checks if there is a comma before the main patter.

`0\.\d+`: This matches a zero followed by a decimal point and one or more digits.

This will match all numbers that start with 0 and are in the Z field (after the last comma).

Hope this helps set you on the right path!

Comment: Your regex does not match anything, see https://regex101.com/r/VuRSxf/1

Answer (score 0):

`\.0\d+\s`

In the example data you posted, spaces separated each *x,y,z* but I suspect that in your actual data, you have *csv* data with *EOL* or `\r\n` separating. The regex above looks for a `.` followed by `0` followed by a string of digits `\d+` followed by a space `\s`. If your real data is CSV, this should work:

`\.0\d+$`

This regex takes advantage of the fact that your *z* field is your final field before the next record. It would get a little more complicated to search the *y* field, but could be done by looking for at most one preceding comma.

Comment: If there is a single line, the regex does not match. See https://regex101.com/r/Y0ued3/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird - you are right, and I also did not match the digits preceding the '.' - your answer should be accepted. Thank you for introducing me to regex101.com as well.